# How do I assign a function to the property of a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I was looking and struggling to the following example:

```
var player1= {name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1};
var player2= {name: "Kristofer", score: 100000, rank: 2};

function playerDetails(){
alert("The name of the player is "+ this.name + "."+ " His score is : "+ this.score + "and his rank : "+ this.rank);
}
player1.logDetails= playerDetails;
player2.logDetails= playerDetails;

player1.logDetails();
player2.logDetails();
```

As far as I know `player1.logDetails` is a property of player1 or a method of player1.
So I can't understand how the author assigns a property to a function. 
Also I don't get why you would write it like that instead of : 
    player1.logDetails= playerDetails();
which I have tried and doesn't work.

Then he calls `player1.logDetails()` which is a function but not declared anywhere.(?)

If anyone could help??
Thank you in advance

Comment: [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/uD6Mm/) for those interested.

Comment: Javascript is different from C# or Java. In Javascript, you can pass the functions as a parameter to another function or any variable. And then call that function as you have seen in your code.

Comment: @KhurramHassan we can pass the function too as parameter in the c# using Delegate.

Comment: @MillerKoijam I never said we cannot pass functions as parameters in C#. I said Javascipt is different from C# or Java, meaning that not to confuse Javascript with these languages and their restrictions are different

Comment: @KhurramHassan So as for the example here: what does `player1.logDetails= playerDetails;` mean and why don't you use this syntax : `player1.logDetails= playerDetails();`. Is there an alternate to writing this code with the same functionality ?

Comment: @atomtm using `player1.logDetails = playerDetails();` would actually execute the function `playerDetails()` and then assign the returned value _(but nothing is being returned in this case here)_ to the property `player1.logDetails`. I hope you have understood what I mean. As for the alternate, I don't think there is any other alternate than `player1.logDetails= playerDetails;`.

Comment: @KhurramHassan I think I get the point but not very clear. If anyone could post any resource for further reading on this subject , that would be much appreciated . Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @atomtm I couldn't find links for your reading. But you can use these following example links I found for better understanding.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883755/assigning-function-within-function-object-without-invoking-the-function-itself
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334383/javascript-function-as-an-object-property
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642140/attach-get-set-function-to-objects-property-in-js
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903407/assigning-defined-function-to-an-object-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: Now that there are classes in ES2015 (ES6) there is an easier way to define objects like this. The [mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) gives a clear description.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If the code was written like this, I bet you understand it:

```
var player1 = {
                name: "Chris", 
                score: 1000, 
                rank: 1,
                playerDetails: function() { alert('The name is '+ this.name) }
};

var player2 = {
                name: "Kristofer", 
                score: 10000, 
                rank: 2,
                playerDetails: function() { alert('The name is '+ this.name) }
};
```

The author of the code wanted to define the "playerDetails()" function once.

Another way of showing this in a simplified manner is:

```
var player1 = {
                name: "Chris", 
                score: 1000, 
                rank: 1
};

player1.playerDetails=function() { alert('The name is '+ this.name) }

var player2 = {
                name: "Kristofer", 
                score: 10000, 
                rank: 2
};

player2.playerDetails=function() { alert('The name is '+ this.name) }
```

So if you wanted to optimize the code above by only writing the playerDetails function once, it would look like the code in your post.

If I had written the code block, I might have written it like this:  (which is easy to read)

```
function playerDetailsFunc() {alert('The name is '+ this.name) }

var player1 = {
                name: "Chris", 
                score: 1000, 
                rank: 1,
                playerDetails: playerDetailsFunc
};

var player2 = {
                name: "Kristofer", 
                score: 10000, 
                rank: 2,
                playerDetails: playerDetailsFunc
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript functions are no different from other values or objects.
You can assign them to whatever you want; you can even pass them as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a newb myself, but you could create the method in the object as an alternative.

```
var player1= {name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1, logDetails: playerDetails};
var player2= {name: "Kristofer", score: 100000, rank: 2, logDetails: playerDetails};

function playerDetails(){
console.log("The name of the player is "+ this.name + "."+ " His score is : "+ this.score + "and his rank : "+ this.rank);
}

player1.logDetails();
player2.logDetails();
```

Also, the link below under "Defining Methods" may help answer your question. 
[enter link description here](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/jscoreguide/obj.html?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var player1= {name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1};
var player2= {name: "Kristofer", score: 100000, rank: 2};

playerDetails = player => console.log( "The name of the player is "+ player.name + "."+ " His score is : "+ player.score + "and his rank : "+ player.rank);
player1.logDetails= playerDetails(player1);
player2.logDetails= playerDetails(player2);
```