# ';' expected . In function p5.js Javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I get an error on line `this.show()` as *`" ';' expected. "`*. I am very new to js so I think it's a simple mistake but I could not figure it out.

```js
function Cell(i,j , height , width , color) {
  this.cellColor = color ; 
  this.cellWidth = width ; 
  this.cellHeight = height; 
  this.x = j; // num from left 
  this.y = i; // num from top 
  this.connectedLimeCells = []; 
  this.connectedBlocks = []; 
  this.connectedOpenWhites = []; 
  this.neighbors = [] ; 
  this.show(){
    fill(this.cellColor) ; 
    noStroke(); 
    rect(this.x * this.cellWidth , this.y * this.cellHeight , this.cellWidth , this.cellHeight); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect-- if you want to assign a function to `this.show` it would be `this.show = function () { /* your fn body */ }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Objects assign function to property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826094/javascript-objects-assign-function-to-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are calling your method.

```
this.show()
```

So the parser expects a `;` after you call `this.show`.
What you meant to do was:

```
this.show = () => {}
```